# What is the error in this code to reverse words of a string individually

Tags: c++

Code is running but dose not give ans, please help. This program is used to print reverse of a word in a string individually. 
I want to make the code with help of function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
char* reverse(char []);
int main()
{
    char sh[100];
    char *v;
    cout<<"Enter the string \n";
    cin.getline(sh,100);
    v=reverse(sh);
    cout<<"The new array is: ";
    for(int i=0;sh[i]!='\0';++i)
    {
        cout<<*(v+i);
    }
    return 0;
}
char* reverse(char a[])
{
    static char t[100];
    char b[100];
    for(int l=0;a[l]!='\0';++l)
    {
        t[l]=a[l];
    }
    int k,j,h;
    for(int i=0;t[i]!='\0';i+=(k+1))
    {

        for(k=i;t[k]!=' ';++k)
            b[k]=t[k];
        for( j=i,h=k-1;t[j]!=' ';++j,h--)
        {

            t[h]=b[j];
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized. Their values will be *indeterminate* and using that value in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You never copy the terminating `NUL` (`'\0'`) from `a` into `t`.

Comment: Did you know that your variables names may contain more than just one letter? Giving them names that actually mean something makes a program much easier to work with. Mentally keeping track of about ten one-letter variables (half of which are pointless) makes for a very annoying debugging experience. Also, if you're coding in C++, I recommend actually using C++ constructs other than `cin`/`cout` and the dreaded `using namespace std;`. `std::string` makes this much easier (and less error prone), and especially `std::reverse` is very helpful here.

Comment: What's the input, what's the expected output and what's the actual output???!!!

Comment: @BoBTFish: He doesn't need to, because he later prints it one character at a time (i.e., not using any null-terminated string functions).

Comment: @goodvibration The loop immediately below the copy iterates over `t` until it encounters a `NUL`. Which it won't.

Comment: You should by the least extend `t[k]!=' '` to `t[k]!=' ' && t[k]!='\0'`.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Maybe that's what you meant ^ ... I mean, in addition to your previous comment...

Comment: @BoBTFish Fortunately it's not needed since the OP is only calling `reverse` once, and `static` local variables (like the buffer `b`) will be zero-initialized. If the OP ever wants to call the function more then it's going to be a problem though.